# 組み合わせの各要素に対し、含まれる任意の2数を取り出して一方を他方で割り、整数になることがない場合の組み合わせの総数を求めるプログラムをご教授ください。

Tags: python

例えば1~4から3数選んだ組み合わせに対し、任意の2数を互いに割った結果が整数にならないものの総数を求めたいです。[2,3,4]を選んだ場合、4が2で割れるので不可とします。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: どんな計算なのか具体例を知りたいです

Comment: 具体例といいますと、どういったことでしょうか？

Comment: 1~4 の場合、組み合わせは `(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)` となるので、総数は `0` になります。これは正しい結果ですか？

Comment: おっしゃる通りです。

Comment: この質問は一体何の役に立つんですか？

Comment: 第一にこのような組み合わせの総数に関して興味を持っただけです。複雑な条件に対するプログラムを学びたいという意図もあります。興味本位での質問であり申し訳ございません。

Comment: 現状だと仕様が提示されているだけで、「プログラムを代わりに書いてください」という依頼のような印象を受けます。 / 「ロジックは分かるけど Python のコードに落とし込めない」や「そもそもロジックをどう考えればいいか分からない」など、もう少し具体的に分からない事を説明してもらった方が "よい質問" になると思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

剰余演算の結果が `0` ではない組み合わせの個数を求めます。

```py
from itertools import combinations

lst = [*range(1, 5)]
cnt = 0
for a in combinations(lst, 3):
    for b in combinations(a, 2):
        if not divmod(*sorted(b, reverse=True))[1]:
            break
    else:
        cnt += 1

print(cnt)
```

Comment: こちらの場合は、どのような場合の数を求めていますでしょうか？

Comment: `[1, 2, 3, 4]` です。`lst = [*range(1, 5)]` の部分を必要に応じて変更してください。

Comment: range, sortedの前につく*は何を表しますか？また、divmod内は選んだ2数を降順に並べて大きい方を小さい方で割っているということで合っていますでしょうか？

Comment: `*` はリストの要素を展開する演算子で、アンパック(unpack)と呼ばれています。「divmod内は〜」はその通りです。

Comment: 理解しました。divmodの後の[1]はどういう意味でしょうか？

Comment: `divmod` の戻り値は `tuple` で、例えば `divmod(a, b)` の結果は `(a//b, a%b)` になります。つまり、この `tuple` の 2 番目の要素である「余り」(`a%b`)を取り出しているのです。

Comment: 細かい話ですが，`b` の要素は昇順に並んでいるので `if b[1] % b[0] == 0:` でも良さそうです。